# How do I create a temporary array of objects, which contain an NSString and an integer?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Within a simple Objective-C method, I want to create a temporary array of objects, where each of these objects contains two elements:

```
{
    NSString *objectName;
    int objectCount;
}
```

This is to be a temporary array, not used outside the method, and not defined in the object interface. How do I define such an array in Objective-C?

Comment: NSMutableArray *myarray = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simply define a helper object:

```
@interface MyHelper
@property(copy) NSString *name;
@property(assign) unsigned int count;
@end

@implementation MyHelper
@end
```

That's it. If you're not using ARC, you'd need to implement `dealloc` to free `name`.

You could also use an array of arrays (very bad) or array of mutable dictionaries (also bad). I wouldn't recommend going that route as it's way more work than just defining the helper object and you lose context. Accessing the name of the first object could look like this:

```
id element = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];

// Helper object
name = element.name; // or [element name]

// Array of arrays
name = [element objectAtIndex:0]; // 0 means "name"... ugh

// Array of dictionaries
name = [element objectForKey:@"name"]; // better than with arrays.
```

So reading the name or count is easy. But things get messy when you want to update something:

```
id element = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];

// Helper object
element.count++; // Easy. Everybody gets it.

// Array of arrays.
// Yuck!
NSNumber *oldValue = [element objectAtIndex:1];
[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject: @[ [element objectAtIndex:0], @([oldValue unsignedIntValue] + 1) ]];
// Or, if the element is actually a mutable array:
[element replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject: @([oldValue unsignedIntValue] + 1)];

// Array of MUTABLE dictionaries
// Better, but still ugly.
oldValue = [element objectForKey:@"count"];
[element setObject:@([oldValue unsignedIntValue] + 1) forKey:@"count"];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create a custom object to store objectName and objectCount, you can use an NSDictionary.

Example:

```
NSString *objectNameKey = @"objectName";
NSString *objectCountKey = @"objectCount";

NSDictionary *tempObject = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"someName", objectNameKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:7], objectCountKey, 
    nil];

NSString *objectName = [tempObject objectForKey:objectNameKey];
int objectCount = [tempObject objectForKey:objectCountKey];
```

Comment: With modern syntax, you can shorten this to: `NSDictionary tempObject = @{ objectNameKey:@"someName", objectCountKey:@(7) };` Way easier to read, IMHO.

Comment: @DarkDust You don't even need the parens around `7` since it's not an expression! You can just use `@7`

Comment: @DarkDust Thanks for adding that. (This is called objective-c literals)

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the class extension in .m file, something like that:

```
@interface YOURCLASSNAME ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tmpArray;
@end
```

And if you want to call is do:

```
self.tempArray = ...
```

or

```
_tempArray = ...
```

Or you can add it as a ivar in .m file, like that:

```
@implementation YOURCLASSNAME {
    NSArray *_tmpArray;
}
```

And you call it like that:

```
_tempArray = ...
```

//Extended

To add object to your array you can do:

```
CustomObject *obj1 = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
obj1.objectName = @"Name 1";
obj1.objectCount = 1;
CustomObject *obj2 = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
obj2.objectName = @"Name 2";
obj2.objectCount = 2;

_tmpArray = @[obj1, obj2];
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but what is the syntax to do this? As you can see, I am struggling a bit with the basics here. I mean, once I declare _tmpArray, how do I add the int and string objects to it? Do I need to create another array that contains these two elements, and then add that array to tmpArray?

Comment: @SillyGoof (1) Make it an NSMutableArray, not an NSArray. Look at the docs for NSMutableArray. (2) You cannot add int object to an NSArray (or an NSDictionary): int is not an object type. You will have to wrap in an NSNumber object.

Comment: See edited answer, it's how you add custom object to the array.